# JavaScript Event Delegation without an actual event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

Hope my title is not too confusing. Please let me know if there is a better way to title my problem.
I have jQuery function applying background-color to the odd rows in a table and on hover change the color to red. But if I edit the table dynamically my jQuery does not work any more. 

I read a lot about JS event delegation and could not find any information about how to make this work without having actual event...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //add background-color to all odd rows
    //very important!!!
    $("#tab3 tbody tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DCF1FD");
    //change color on hover 
    //less important!!!     
    $("#tab3 tbody tr").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#000");
      }
    );
});
```

Is there a way to make it work after I edit the table. 

EDIT:
This must work on IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jQuery `delegate` on the table that will work even if you update the table rows dynamically because the event is attached to table and not each rows of it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tab3 tbody tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DCF1FD");


    $("#tab3").delegate('tbody tr', 'hover', function(){
        $(this).css("color", "red");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#000");
    });
});
```

If you are updating the whole table dynamically then use this

```
$(document).delegate('#tab3 tbody tr', 'hover', function(){
        $(this).css("color", "red");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#000");
 });
```

You can set the background color of odd row with simple css

```
#tab3 tbody tr:nth-child(odd)
{ 
   background: #DCF1FD; 
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but what about the background-color for the odd rows?

Comment: It can be easily controlled through css class

Comment: Check my edited answer I have added the required style for row background color.

Comment: In that case, when you update the table you can just call this line `$("#tab3 tbody tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DCF1FD");`

Comment: @Radi - If it is all fine please mark it as an answer whenever you can thanks.

Answer (score 0):

... Or you could just use CSS to define the backgrounds for even rows, odd rows and the hover state. Se the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+rows+even+odd).
(EDIT: fixed link, it was pointing the wrong SO thread).

Comment: No, not even IE9 according to [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx). :(

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong SO article. Will edit the link. What I meant was actually `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)`. IE support begins in IE9, I think.

Comment: I already know about these CSS selectors [LINK](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd).